# How do I do a Barplot of already tabled data?

Tags: r

I have input data with very many observations per day.
I can make the `barplot` I want with 1 day by using `table()`.

If I try to load more than 1 day and call `table()` I run out of memory.

I'm trying to table() each day and concatenate the tables into totals I can then `barplot` later. But I just cannot work out how to take the already `table`d data and barplot each day as a stacked column.

After looping and consolidating I end up with something like this: 2 days of observations. *(the `Freq` column is the default from the previous `table()` calls)*

What is the best way to do a stacked barplot when my data ends up like this?

```
> data.frame(CLIENT=c("Mr Fluffy","Peppa Pig","Mr Fluffy","Dr Who"), Freq=c(18414000,9000000,7000000,15000000), DAY=c("2011-11-03","2011-11-03","2011-11-04","2011-11-04"))
     CLIENT     Freq        DAY
1 Mr Fluffy 18414000 2011-11-03
2 Peppa Pig  9000000 2011-11-03
3 Mr Fluffy  7000000 2011-11-04
4    Dr Who 15000000 2011-11-04
>
> # What should I put here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using base graphics since you mention `barplot`. Here is an approach using that:

```
wide <- reshape(dat, idvar="CLIENT", timevar="DAY", direction="wide")
barplot(as.matrix(wide[-1]), beside=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, using `ggplot2`:

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(dat, aes(x=DAY, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=CLIENT), position="stack")
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for your answer. There is a slight problem with the barplot output in that the `NA` values genereated by `reshape` mess up the final `barplot` representation. I fixed this up by putting in `0` instead. e.g. `wide[is.na(wide)] <- 0` . BTW I _was_ looking for the barplot (though thanks for the ggplot2) because I've found ggplot2 runs out of memory on some different graphs of the same data :(

Answer (score 1):

Try ggplot2:

```
ggplot(df,aes(DAY,fill=CLIENT,weight=Freq))+geom_bar()
```

Shamelessly ripped from here:

http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html

Comment: ggplot2 runs out of memory for my large dataset (nanosecond samples )